# Verify email in PHP or other programming language?

Tags: php, email, smtp, verify

How can i make a script like verify-email.org ?
I told in the school, that this is not a problem. But now,  I searched the web, and found nothing?

E.g. test123@hotmail.com

- I don't want only check if the domain exist of the E-Mail address. I want check, the whole E-Mail, if it exists on Hotmail.com?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You have to send an email and wait for an answer to verify that this address exists.

Answer (score 1):

The only clear way to check an email address is valid is to send it an email. If it isn't valid you will get an undelivered response.

Comment: Even that would not be 100% precise.

Comment: Unless the server just swallows mail to unknown mail boxes on the (not entirely unreasonable) assumption that it is scatter bomb spam.

Answer (score 0):

Like my predecessors wrote, you can only completely veryfiy by sending a mail to the address.

However, you could use DNS to check if the domain exists and a MX (Mail Exchange) record is associated with it. 
It's not a complete solution, but maybe a step that brings you a little further.

Comment: You should check the format of the email first against a good regular expression - then do an MX lookup on the domain - then try to send an email with an authentication link.

Comment: Why don't you post this as answer? Providing an authentication link for a web service is maybe exactly what PhpHelper is wanting.