# "Pinging" an email address using VB.Net coding

Tags: vb.net, email, ping, verify

Is there a way in VB.Net to "Ping" an email address to see if that email is a real one that does not give any errors?

If yes, can you show what the VB.Net coding looks like to implement this?

I plan to use this in an app that requires the Customer email and it would be nice to validate it as the call taker enters it into a form before saving the Customer details.

Here is the code we are using to send an email promotion to all of the customers in our customer table:

```
Private Sub RibbonButtonSendTestEmail_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RibbonButtonSendTestEmail.Click

    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    Dim strSqlStatement As String = "Select CustomerName, Email " & _
                               "From Customers "

    Using objSqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strSqlStatement, ObjConnection)

        With objSqlCommand

            ' Open the SqlConnection before executing the query.
            '---------------------------------------------------
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

            ObjConnection.Open()

            Dim objDataReader As SqlDataReader = .ExecuteReader()

            ' Go through all the customers and send out the promotion emails.
            '----------------------------------------------------------------
            If objDataReader.HasRows Then

                SmtpServer.Host = TextBoxSMTPServer.Text
                SmtpServer.Port = TextBoxPort.Text

                If TextBoxUseSSL.Text = "Yes" Then
                    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
                Else
                    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = False
                End If

                If TextBoxUseDefaultCredentials.Text = "Yes" Then
                    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = True
                Else
                    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
                End If

                SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(TextBoxUserName.Text, TextBoxPassword.Text)

                While objDataReader.Read()

                    Try
                        mail.To.Add(objDataReader("Email").ToString)
                        mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBoxEmailFrom.Text)
                        mail.Subject = "Promotion: " & TextBoxID.Text
                        mail.Body = "Dear " & objDataReader("CustomerName") & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & TextBoxPromotionBodyText.Text

                        SmtpServer.Send(mail)

                    Catch exSMTP As SmtpException
                        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, I could not send an email for: " & _
                                    vbCrLf & objDataReader("CustomerName") & "." & vbCrLf & _
                                    "Please make sure it is correct.", _
                                    "Error")

                    Catch exFormat As FormatException
                        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, this customer's email is not properly formatted: " & _
                                    vbCrLf & objDataReader("CustomerName") & "." & vbCrLf & _
                                    "Please make sure it is correct.", _
                                    "Error")
                    End Try
                End While

                LabelEmail.Text = "Sent email promotions to the customers."
            End If

            objDataReader.Close()
            ObjConnection.Close()

            Cursor = Cursors.Default
        End With ' objSqlCommand
    End Using ' objSqlCommand
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verify email in PHP or other programming language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733138/verify-email-in-php-or-other-programming-language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly possible:

*1* **DNS Lookup the MX records for the domain**

- There may be multiples, you can pick anyone, although technically the one with the lowest preference indicator is the prefered one.

*2* **TCP Connect to the mail server (port 25)**

- Say hello: `HELO`
- Identify yourself: `mail from:<test@example.com>`
- Say who you're writing to: `rcpt to<testaddress@example.com>`
- At this point the server will reply with a response, you'll get an `OK` or a `550` error with a message (like: `The email account that you tried to reach does not exist`)
- Disconnect and the message will be dropped.

But dude, you want the VB code to do this?  You just need a DNS talking piece and TCP connection building piece (or likely there are some SMTP libraries out there that'll do all this for you - or provide you with inspiration to figure it out yourself).  Don't forget you can probably find a C# code example that does it and use Visual Studio's conversion tool to switch it to VB.

**Note**

Many domains have black holes/catch alls... the former will accept any email address and just delete it if it's invalid, the latter will accept any email address and forward them to a central account (no guarantees as to what happens then... sell the sender's address to spammers?)  In both cases you won't get the `550` message, so you can never be certain.

Answer (score 1):

There most reliable way to do this is to send a test email and have the recipient verify receipt by clicking on a link, which you then read and mark the email as active.

You should do primitive checks on the syntax of the email using regular expressions, but beyond that the *most reliable* way to validate an email is to attempt delivery and confirm the receipt.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. I'm including an update to the posting so you know how I'm sending out the emails. It's a loop that goes through each customer in the database and will send out emails for promotions when we create those sale promotions.